# how to convert javascript to angularjs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

i am trying to load openlayer maps but i want to load map by using angularjs.
you can find openlayer example here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/accessible.html

```
<div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>
```

js script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var g = new gs("map", { debug: true , language:'nl' });
    </script>
```

how can i load this code in agularjs
Please help

Comment: One way, use angular `directive` and use same openlayer  JS code there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very basic you want to write a directive:

```
angular.module('yourModule')
    .directive('loadMap', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) { 
          new gs(element, { debug: true , language:'nl' }); // if this is enough to show the map
        }
    }
});
```

In your template:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 500px;" load-map></div>
```

Comment: it is not working, i tried to create directive but gs is defines in another javascript file(mapgs.js) in this file code is written in javascript not in angular.

Comment: You're going to have to figure it out, but that's how you integrate non-angular code into the angular app. We can't write your code for you. Code for `gs` does not have to be angular.